# Force a download manager not to manage downloads

Tags: downloading, chrome-for-android, download-manager

I have a nexus 7 and I use chrome on it for my browser. I have a download manager installed, and I use it to download files by URL. However, it has usurped the downloading of chrome, and I like chrome's way of downloads better. Can I change the default download opener in chrome? (I'm running Jelly Bean 4.2)

Comment: What is the name of the download manager you are using?

Comment: I am currently using something called `Android Download Manager`, but I am open to using anything which will download a pasted/typed URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has a "defaults"-system for handling predefined requests such as opening a URL or pressing the home button. If you go into Android's `System Settings` -> `Apps` -> `Android Download Manager` and scroll down to "LAUNCH BY DEFAULT", you should see a button to clear the defaults. The next time you open your chrome browser and tap on a URL that has the `<a download="">` property, a screen should pop up, asking you to choose which application to use for downloading.

Comment: I assume this would work, but I already wrote an app to do the downloading for me and nothing else, so I uninstalled `Android Download Manager`.